# creating a python web page

Tags: python, html

I am working on a small task.

the task requires me to process the data from a html form. the html form consists of a phone dial pad. the data is the phone number the user enters. I need to process the data. The functionality for processing of phone number (data) has been completed.

But i have a problem. I am used to django framework. But for this task, the database is not needed and i do not need a admin page as well. In short, i do not want to use a framework for a single web page.

Is there any possible ways for me to create a simple html form, and when i submit the form the data is transferred to the python code for processing.

I have been looking over through the internet, and i am not finding any suitable ways of implementing it. can you please help me out or point me in the right direction

Comment: Look into [Python Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) - it is a micro-framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact idea about [Python Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) but you'll have to do the something similar to the following

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def calculation():
    #manipute request here as per your 
    #pass manipulated data to the processing functionality already present


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

Suppose this code now runs at `http://localhost/`, in HTML code, you'll have to write a form processing JavaScript code that'll parse the form. You can use any method `.serialize()` or anything else depending on what you are comfortable with. Then make an Ajax call to the running `Flask` code and to it pass the request parameters.

You can then probably host this Flask code on `Heroku` or something similar. Here is method that's creating RESTful web API using Flask. You can read through it and understand the workings of it. http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html